# Storing object position and rotation

Tags: opengl-es2

I only superficially understand the idea and I can't find any thorough explanation (partially because I can't find very good keywords to Google - English is not my first language):

Although I partially understand some things (next paragraph), my question is what data structure would you use to store a body's position and rotation and how does everything come together? I want to be able to translate that object to a (x, y) position, rotate it about the origin or about its centre (then fetch these things and draw a sprite using that position and rotation). Very similar to Unity's `Transform` object.

From my understanding I will need (at least) a 2/3-dimensional vector and a quaternion and then I should be able to generate a model matrix from them. How? Multiply what to what and in what order? I certainly have no idea how to get a 4 x 4 matrix from a 2/3-dimensional vector and a quaternion. Then if I change the position, I should probably update the model matrix again.

I'm using OpenGL ES 2 on Android, but I wouldn't mind an agnostic answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use directx but it should be the same.
There are some functions that create a matrix from a vector.
You can search for "transformation matrix". 
ex.
a 2d translation matrix:

```
[1 0 x]
[0 1 y]
[0 0 1]
```

a 2d scaling matrix:

`[sx 0 0]
[0 sy 0]
[0 0 1]`

to obtain the final world matrix you have to multiply them, but be careful the order is important ( matrices haven't commutative property)
so:
if you do
-scale*position= the model is scaled about its centre and then translated
-position* scale = the model is first translated and then scaled (it will move to the origin)
-position* rotation = the model will rotate around the origin and not around its centre

usually you need world = rotation*scale*position.

In directx there is a function for each transformation:
XMMatrixTranslation(x,y,z)
XMMatrixRotationZ(r)
....
each of them returns a matrix.

I think in opengl there are function like these so you dont need vector to stroe value, of course you can but you can use:
float px,py,pz;
float sx,sy,sz;
float rx,ry,rz;
or three arrays and then call translationMatrix=XMMAtrixTranslation(px,py,pz) or 
( XMMatrixTranslation(position[0],position[1],position[2])